# install quilljs-markdown on react

Tags: reactjs, markdown, editor, quill, react-quill

I need such an editor on react https://cloverhearts.github.io/quilljs-markdown/ , as you can see in it you can put markdown characters directly into the text.

when I do this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill'
import Quill from 'quill'
import QuillMarkdown from 'quilljs-markdown'




const App = () => {
  const editor = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  })
  new QuillMarkdown(editor)

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      {/*<MyComponent/>*/}
      <div id="editor"></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I get error TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

[image]

as I understand I need jQuery for work, but I use react, I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill this quilljs for react, but I don't know how to combine it with markdown https://www.npmjs.com/package/quilljs-markdown
can anyone help?

Comment: Does it have to be `quill`? I'd avoid jQuery as it doesn't play well with react and increases the bundle size. There is [react-mde](https://github.com/andrerpena/react-mde) and you can use [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) to display the input. See a live example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mde-latest-5i5ov?file=/src/index.js

Comment: in your example, inserting markdown into text don't work (((

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this after hours of trying this out.

What you have to do is this:

1. Create a module for `ReactQuill`
2. Register the module.
3. Pass modules to react quill

Shown Below.

Step 01

```
const modules = {
  markdownOptions: {}
};
```

Step 02

```
Quill.register('modules/markdownOptions', QuillMarkdown);
```

Step 03

```
<ReactQuill
    modules={modules}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to initialize the Quill instance and the markdown module before the editor  is ready.

Use `useEffect` hook to initialize it after the div has been rendered:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

...

useEffect(() => {
  const editor = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });

  new QuillMarkdown(editor);
});
```

Comment: did this implementation work?